# Find sort and seperate an array of date in year in month in php

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, datetime

I have an array of dates like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 10-19-2016
    [1] => 10-29-2016
    [2] => 11-08-2016
    [3] => 11-18-2016
    [4] => 11-28-2016
    [5] => 12-08-2016
    [6] => 12-18-2016
    [7] => 12-28-2016
    [8] => 01-07-2017
    [9] => 01-17-2017
    [10] => 01-27-2017
    [11] => 02-06-2017
    [12] => 02-16-2017
    [13] => 02-18-2017
    [14] => 02-26-2017
    [15] => 03-08-2017
    [16] => 03-18-2017
    [17] => 03-28-2017
    [18] => 03-30-2017
    [19] => 04-07-2017
    [20] => 04-09-2017
)
```

How can I sort and separate them into year, month and day so that it will look like the following?

```
2016 oct 19,20 nov 08,18,28... 2017 jan 07,17
```

Comment: Where are you stuck at doing this?

Answer (score -1):

```
 $result_arr=[];
$date_arr=array("10-19-2016","10-29-2016","11-08-2016","11-28-2016");
foreach($date_arr as $date)
{
    $date_arr=explode("-",$date);   
    $act_date=$date_arr[1]."-".$date_arr[0]."-".$date_arr[2];
    $result_arr[strtotime($act_date)]=date("Y M d",strtotime($act_date));

}
ksort($result_arr);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($result_arr);
```

Hope it will help

Comment: I have thought about that method, i think i can develop from there. thank you so much